# Pagamento recorrente com webservice 3.0 da Cielo

Tags: php, e-commerce

Estou testando o exemplo de pagamento recorrente, disponível no [repositório oficial da Cielo](https://github.com/DeveloperCielo/API-3.0-PHP#criando-um-pagamento-recorrente) e o código retorna o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setInterval()
>   on null in /var/www/public/page.php:24

```
$recurrent = $recurrent->setInterval(RecurrentPayment::INTERVAL_MONTHLY)->setAuthorizeNow(true);
```

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Código completo:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Cielo\API30\Merchant;

use Cielo\API30\Ecommerce\Environment;
use Cielo\API30\Ecommerce\Sale;
use Cielo\API30\Ecommerce\CieloEcommerce;
use Cielo\API30\Ecommerce\Payment;

use Cielo\API30\Ecommerce\Request\CieloRequestException;
// ...
// Configure o ambiente
$environment = $environment = Environment::sandbox();

// Configure seu merchant
$merchant = new Merchant('MERCHANT ID', 'MERCHANT KEY');

// Crie uma instância de Sale informando o ID do pagamento
$sale = new Sale('123');

// Crie uma instância de Customer informando o nome do cliente
$customer = $sale->customer('Fulano de Tal');

// Configure a recorrência
$recurrent = $recurrent->setInterval(RecurrentPayment::INTERVAL_MONTHLY)
                        ->setAuthorizeNow(true);

// Crie uma instância de Payment informando o valor do pagamento
$payment = $sale->payment(15700);

// Crie uma instância de Credit Card utilizando os dados de teste
// esses dados estão disponíveis no manual de integração
$payment->setRecurrentPayment($recurrent)
        ->setType(Payment::PAYMENTTYPE_CREDITCARD)
        ->creditCard("123", "Visa")
        ->setExpirationDate("12/2018")
        ->setCardNumber("0000000000000001")
        ->setHolder("Fulano de Tal");

// Crie o pagamento na Cielo
try {
    // Configure o SDK com seu merchant e o ambiente apropriado para criar a venda
    $sale = (new CieloEcommerce($merchant, $environment))->createSale($sale);

    // Com a venda criada na Cielo, já temos o ID do pagamento, TID e demais
    // dados retornados pela Cielo
    $paymentId = $sale->getPayment()->getPaymentId();

    // Com o ID do pagamento, podemos fazer sua captura, se ela não tiver sido capturada ainda
    $sale = (new CieloEcommerce($merchant, $environment))->captureSale($paymentId, 15700, 0);

    // E também podemos fazer seu cancelamento, se for o caso
    $sale = (new CieloEcommerce($merchant, $environment))->cancelSale($paymentId, 15700);
} catch (CieloRequestException $e) {
    // Em caso de erros de integração, podemos tratar o erro aqui.
    // os códigos de erro estão todos disponíveis no manual de integração.
    $error = $e->getCieloError();
}
```

Comment: Estranho que o objeto `$recurrent` não foi definido no exemplo. Será que faltou um `$recurrent = $payment->getRecurrent()`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss coloquei um `$recurrent = $payment->getRecurrent();`, mas retornou Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRecurrent() on null para essa linha.

Comment: Coloque seu código inteiro na pergunta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss incluído.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido: é necessário acrescentar a classe no topo: 
`use Cielo\API30\Ecommerce\RecurrentPayment;`

e instanciar a variável `$recurrent`:

```
$recurrent = new RecurrentPayment();
$recurrent = $recurrent->setInterval(RecurrentPayment::INTERVAL_MONTHLY)->setAuthorizeNow(true);
```